# Node http request using existing socket

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy

I am trying to write an `express` application which proxies HTTP requests through an ssh tunnel. The package `ssh2`  can create the tunnel using `forwardOut()`. It creates a stream which is connected to the port on the remote machine. I am now trying to forward an incoming HTTP request through this connection.

The problem I am facing is that each proxy library and even HTTP library I found creates a new socket to the host, but I want to use the stream from `forwardOut()` instead of a new socket.

I could try to create an additional server which forwards everything through the tunnel, but creating additional sockets for each request sounds very hacky. I hope there is a better way.

Is there any library which supports using an existing socket/stream for the HTTP request?

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered a similar situation. I used the existing socket by returning the `stream` created by `ssh2` in the option parameters of `http.request()` (the Node.js HTTP client). Some example code:

```
var http = require('http');
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var conn = new Client();

conn.on('ready', function () {
  // The connection is forwarded to '0.0.0.0' locally.
  // Port '0' allows the OS to choose a free TCP port (avoids race conditions)
  conn.forwardOut('0.0.0.0', 0, '127.0.0.1', 80, function (err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // End connection on stream close
    stream.on('close', function() {
      conn.end();
    }).end();

    // Setup HTTP request parameters
    requestParams = {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/',
      createConnecion: function() {
        return stream; // This is where the stream from ssh2 is passed to http.request()
      }
    };

    var request = http.request(requestParams, function(response) {
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        // Do whatever you need to do with 'chunk' (the response body)
        // Note, this may be called more than once if the response data is long
      })
    });

    // Send request
    request.end();
  });
}).connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password'
});
```

I had an issue where `socket.destroySoon()` was not defined, as a workaround it can be defined before the `stream` is returned. It simply calls `socket.destroy()` instead. Example:

```
createConnection: function () {
    stream.destroySoon = function () {
        return stream.destroy();
    }

    return stream;
}
```

Note: I have not fully tested the examples, so use at your own risk.